# multiple h1 tags in the same line not working when one of them is hidden

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put two h1 tags in the same line like this:

```
<h1 class="hello">hello world</h1><h1>you are welcome</h1>
```

and css code is like:

```
.hello{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 0;
}
```

I want to animate hello class from width 0 to 100 but the two h1 tags must still in the same line,if I use display property the hello class will appear without animating.any idea to make the two h1 tags in the same line with these informations? I do not want to use nowrap for a purpose

thanks any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can two h1's to appear in a single line use display-inline block or display:flex

check this snippet

```css
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="hello">hello world</h1>
<h1>you are welcome</h1>
```

```css
header {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 class="hello">hello world</h1>
  <h1>you are welcome</h1>
  <header>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks a lot,inline-block and inline not working but flex works fine.